# React-native: Issues when rendering info fetched from an api for each component inside a flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, react-native-flatlist

I'm developing an app in react-native but I'm still a beginner so I think I'm doing something wrong.

The logic behing the app is the following:

- First, I fetch a list of restaurants from an API
- For each of the restaurant, I display a "card" with all relevant information, inside a flatlist
- For each restaurant, I need to fetch data from a second API (whose url depends on the id of the restaurant) to get its opening hours. Then I want to show a label "open" or "close" for each restaurant

The last step is the one giving me troubles. I tried two different approaches, but each of them has its own issue.

First of all, the part in common:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      let isMounted = true;
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:  
              {
                  'Content-Type'    : 'application/json',
                  'Accept'          : 'application/json'
              }              
            }
          )
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json()
        })
        .then((json) => { 
          if (isMounted)
            setData(json)
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => {isMounted=false } );
    }, []);
```

The list of restaurants is saved into the "data" state as an array of objects. Each restaurant has two fields 'site_id' and 'source' which are needed to fetch the opening hours from another api.

Restaurants are then rendered inside a flatlist:

```
           <FlatList 
             data={data}
             renderItem={item => renderItem(item)}
             keyExtractor={restaurant => restaurant.site_id}
           />
```

where renderItem is as follows:

```
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <RestaurantCard 
          source={item.source}
          site_id={item.site_id}
          />
    )
```

And RestaurantCard shows various info about each restaurant. To simplify:

```
    const RestaurantCard = props => (
          //some other info
          <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0 }}>
              // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SHOW IF THE RESTAURANT IS OPEN OR CLOSE
          </View>
```

So now the two approaches I used to render the opening hours info:

## Approach 1

When I fetch the list of restaurant, I run over each item in the list and call a new function 'saveOpeninghours':

```
        .then((json) => { 
          if (isMounted)
            setData(json)
            for (let item of json.results) {
              saveOpeninghours(item.source,item.site_id)
            }
        })
```

This function then call the correspondent API for each restaurant in order to retrieve the opening hours info. This info is saved into a state  array called 'isOpen'

```
 const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState([]);

 const saveOpeninghours = (source,site_id) => {

          let isMounted = true;
          fetch(restaurantUrl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers:  {
                      'Content-Type'    : 'application/json',
                      'Accept'          : 'application/json',
                  }               
                }
              )
            .then((response) => {
              return response.json()
            })
            .then((openingHours) => { 
              if (isMounted)
                if(openingHours) {
                     //Do some stuff to determine if the restaurant is open or not
                          setIsOpen(isOpen => [...isOpen,{site_id:site_id,is_open:is_open}])
                        }
                      }
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error(error))
            .finally(() => isMounted=false );
  };
```

So the array will contain a list of objects in the form

```
{site_id:'18',is_open:true}
```

Then, I use another function to render this info for each restaurant:

```
const renderIsOpen = useCallback( (site_id,source) => {
  let index = isOpen.findIndex(obj => obj.site_id === site_id)
  if(index>0) {
    if(isOpen[index].is_open) {
      return( <Text> Open </Text>)
    }
    else {
      return( <Text> Close </Text>)
    }
  }
},[isOpen])
```

I used a callback with [isOpen] as dependency because I want to wait until the array is filled with all restaurants.

And then in the RestaurantCard I simply call this render function:

```
    const RestaurantCard = props => (
          //some other info
              <View>{renderIsOpen(props.site_id,props.source)}</View>
)
```

This works fine for almost all restaurants but, the problem is that the first restaurant in the list (and sometimes the second one) never shows the 'open/close' label. I think the reason is that the 'isOpen' state is not filled yet when the first restaurant is displayed, but then for the other restaurants the info is finally there and so for them there is no such problem.
I thought that using the callback with isOpen as dependency could solve the problem and force the component to re-render and show the open/close label, but it doesn't work.

## Approach 2

This is the simpler one. I created a separate component which is called for each restaurant and retrieves/renders the opening hours info:

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => true;

const OpeningHours = React.memo(props => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState();
        
          let isMounted = true;
          fetch(restaurantUrl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers:  {
                      'Content-Type'    : 'application/json',
                      'Accept'          : 'application/json',
                  }               
                }
              )
            .then((response) => {
              return response.json()
            })
            .then((openingHours) => { 
              if (isMounted)
                if(openingHours) {
                          // do some stuff to determine if the restaurant is open or not
                          setIsOpen(is_open) //this is true or false
                        }
                      }
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error(error))
            .finally(() => isMounted=false );

  
    if(isOpen) {
      return(
          <Text> Open </Text>  
      )
    }
    else {
      return(
          <Text> Close </Text>  
      )
    }

}, areEqual);

export default OpeningHours;
```

And then, in my RestaurantCard shown before, I simply call this component passing 'source' and 'site_id' as props:

```
    const RestaurantCard = props => (
          //some other info
              <OpeningHours
                source={props.source}
                site_id={props.site_id}
              />
)
```

The problems with this approach are:

- It is quite slow: the open/close labels are shown with few seconds of delay in the restaurant card. However, this is not the major problem, which is instead the following:
- In the RestaurantCard I also have a Button the user can press to add/remove that restaurant from favourites. When the button is pressed, the OpeningHours is re-rendered, so the open/close labels appear/disappear, which is quite annoying to see. As you can see I tried to wrap the component inside 'React.memo' to prevent this re-rendering, but it doesn't work.

---

So basically I'm trying to figure out

1. What is the best approach? I assume it's the second one since it's simpler but, it seems quite slower compared the the first one (btw the list of restaurant is not that big, only 10 items)
2. How to solve the issue related to the chosen approach?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm honestly wondering why the first approach "worked" at all? `setIsOpen({site_id:site_id,is_open:is_open})` looks like each restaurant's fetch call simply overwrites the one isOpen state when it finishes. Anyway, if you don't like your cards populating themselves after a short delay, the alternative is to get *all* data first, and only then display the list. You can do this by using Promise.all() on an array of fetch calls. You should also definitely refactor your fetch code into a hook or just a function so you don't have to write all that `headers` and `.json()` code over and over again.

Comment: Correct, there was actually a typo in the code I wrote here, the correct line there was 
setIsOpen(isOpen => [...isOpen,{site_id:site_id,is_open:true}]) (now edited in the original post)
That's why it was working.

With approach #2, the major problem is not the sloweness actually, but the fact that the open/close label re-renders every time the user press on the 'save' button on the restaurant

Comment: If you lift up the isOpen state to the parent component of the list and pass it down as props it won't refetch the opening hours it time the cards are re-rendered.

Comment: Mm, but how can I achieve this? The problem is that I can't have a single "isOpen" state for each restaurant to pass down to the component (since I have many restaurants)

Comment: Yes, you need an array for this. However looking at your first comment, the update you have there will mess up the order. You need to overwrite a specific array element based on the id of the restaurant. Let me come up with example code.

Comment: Yes indeed, if I use an array and I try this inside the component:
`props.setIsOpen([...props.isOpen,{site_id:props.site_id,is_open:true}])`
Some weird stuff happen (I suppose because the component is called simultaneously for every restaurant, and this makes a mess with the state array) - The labels open/close turn on and off continuously for all restaurants

Comment: Hi, Just want to say that I found a solution. Basically I moved all the logic from the OpeningHours component directly into the RestaurantCard, so I can handle everything inside there. Doing like this, it works quite fine and with no lag. I will write down an answer later to clarify. Thanks again anyway!

Comment: After checking better, it seems I was actually wrong in my last comment. Moving everything inside the RestaurantCard did not solve the problem - the opening hour info is still shown with a significant lag, and still re-renders every time the user presses the button.

Comment: I tried a few things and came up with the following: 1. await fetching restaurant info 2. setData(restaurants) to populate cards 3. await Promise.all() loading all open/close states and map restaurants array to new array also containing the open/close state 4. setData(restaurantsOpenCloseInfo) This *should* avoid a delay of rendering the list until all opening hours are loaded but also avoid your card components loading the info over and over again, since it is part of the parent state and simply passed down as prop